# ZF2 and Doctrine2 weird print

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zfdoctrine

I'm trying to integrate Doctrine2 and ZF2. I can succesfully create a Doctrine Entity and then sync it to my database so the table is created but when I go to the webpage this appears:
[image: ZF2 weird characters]

See those weird characters at the top of the page, and yes, the filename for my entity is UauthEntity.php

My configuration files are:

ZendProject/config/autoload/doctrine.local.php

```
<?php

$dbParams = array(
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 3306,
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'database' => 'project001'
);

return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'params' => array(
                    'host' => $dbParams['hostname'],
                    'port' => $dbParams['port'],
                    'user' => $dbParams['username'],
                    'password' => $dbParams['password'],
                    'dbname' => $dbParams['database'],
                    'driverOptions' => array(
                        \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
                    ),
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

ZendProject/config/application.config.php

```
<?php
return array(
    // This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
    'modules' => array(
        'ZendDeveloperTools',
        'DoctrineModule',
        'DoctrineORMModule',
        'Application',
        'Uauth',
        'Album',
    ), //etc... (default in ZendSkeletonApplication)
```

ZendProject/module/Uauth/config/module.config.php (doctrine configuration at bottom)

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Uauth\Controller\Uauth' => 'Uauth\Controller\UauthController',
        ),
    ),
    // The following section is new and should be added to your file
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'uauth' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/uauth[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Uauth\Controller\Uauth',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'uauth' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
    'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            'uauth_entities' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Uauth/Model/Entity')
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    'Model\Entity' => 'uauth_entities'
                )
            ))),
);
```

and the entity is in ZendProject/module/Uauth/src/Uauth/Model/Entity/UauthEntity.php.

I'll appreciate some help with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere you have a v`var_dump` or whatsoever which prints this. There is no feature in ZF2 or Doctrine which prints information like this, so it must come from somewhere. Try to disable the `UAth` module (to be certain that dump is inside the module) and then check page for page in this module to see where the problem hides.

Comment: Problem solved. The module that is prinnting this stuff out is ZendDeveloperTools. If I disable this module, everything works fine.